# Cmake Xcode project storyboard can not be loaded

Tags: xcode, storyboard, cmake

I have been learning how to use CMake to generate a Xcode project. I found a nice example from https://github.com/forexample/testapp. When I generate Xcode project from this testApp. I always experienced "The document "MainStoryboard_***.storyboard" could not be opened. Unrecognized file content"

I have tried that I could open MainStoryboard_***.storyboard from Xcode if I only open this storyboard without open *.xcodeproj file. I have tried to change configuration in the info.plist and cmakelists.txt files, I didn't find a solution yet.

I wonder if someone experienced this issue before,

Answer (score 15):

I ran into this issue whilst resolving a merge conflict between two storyboards. For me, all I had to do was manually resolve all the merges by opening the storyboard as Source Code and deleting the unwanted code and markers, but Xcode refused to open the file in Interface Builder until I shut Xcode and the simulator down entirely, re-opened them and then selected 'Open In Interface Builder' on the storyboard file.

I'm guessing your problem is more likely to be a bug in CMake, but I couldn't confirm this. I just wanted to drop this answer in for people who suffer this issue due to the same cause as myself.

Comment: the good and old close and restart. I spent on hour after having manually fixed the conflicts originated by a git merge.

Comment: I am getting used to restarting Xcode as #1 step to resolve all sorts of problems.

Comment: Restarting Xcode and the simulator worked for me. Thanks!